Can npm optional dependencies be chained?
I have a Node.js project that is enhanced by, but does not require, package foo. However, it only works if package bar is also installed, and bar is not directly required by foo.
I currently have foo and bar listed as separate entries in optionalDependencies like so:
"optionalDependencies": {
  "foo": "1.x",
  "bar": "2.x"
}

However, this can result in the user installing foo for the enhancement but getting errors instead because they didn't install bar. The optionalDependencies property expects strings, but ideally I would like to encapsulate them in an object kind of like this:
"optionalDependencies": {
  "enhancement-module-group": {
    "foo": "1.x",
    "bar": "2.x"
  }
}

Is it possible to indicate this all-or-none group of optional dependencies in my package.json file?

I'm not aware of a way to do this directly in a package.json declaration.
One option is to create a "ficitive" wrapper package for both of these optional dependencies. That package will non-optionally depend on foo and bar, and would be optionally depended on by the "main" project:
The main project's package.json can look like this:
{
    "name": "main-project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "optionalDependencies": {
        "foobar": "1.0.0"
    }
}

And then you'll have foobar depend on both foo and bar:
{
    "name": "foobar",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "foo": "1.2.3",
        "bar": "4.5.6"
    }
}

In theory this removes some flexibility to install foo without installing bar (or vise-versa), but this flexibility doesn't seem to be useful anyway, since the feature requires both of them, and having just one probably won't be too useful.
Additioanlly, if the feature requires both packages to be present, you should explicitly check that in your code. E.g.:
let featureActive = true;
const requiredPackages = ['foo', 'bar'];
for (package of requiredPackages) {
    try {
        require(package);
    } catch {
        // At least one of the required packages isn't install
        // Feature can't be used
        featureActive = false;
        break;
    }
}

